Trying to take data from database from two diff tables
    public SKU sku(String code) {
        List<SearchParams> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new SearchParams("code", Constants.QueryComparator.EQUALS, code));
        params.add(new SearchParams("active", Constants.QueryComparator.EQUALS, true));
        List<SKU> results = genericDao.loadAll(params, SKU.class, -1, -1).getResults();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(results))
            return results.get(0);
        return null;
    }

this is the code i written to take data from SKU entity but when i tried to get data from SkuDates entity then its not working it is showing internal 500 error
I tried the every possible solution and i am expecting that i want to take data from database like the code written and combine that data with sku table.
